# Filtering LINQ results in ASP.NET Web Forms with pagination

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, linq-to-sql, webforms

I'm trying to filter the contents of a GridView, however I'm getting some off behaviour in the process:

The contents of the asp page look like this:

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">

<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
<asp:Button ID="button1" runat="server" onclick="button1_Click" Text="Submit" />
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" AllowPaging="true" PageSize="8"
AutoGenerateColumns="false" runat="server"
OnPageIndexChanging="GridView1_PageIndexChanging">

<Columns>
  <asp:BoundField HeaderText="ID" DataField="ID" />
  <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Client Name" DataField="Client_Name" />
  <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Project" DataField="Project_Name" />
  <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Uploaded By" DataField="Uploaded_By" />
</Columns>

</asp:GridView>
</form>
```

And the code behind file:

```
public partial class Sample1 : System.Web.UI.Page
{
  protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
    if (!this.Page.IsPostBack)
    {
        SourceDataContext db = new SourceDataContext();

        GridView1.DataSource = from q in db.Cust
                               orderby q.ID
                               select q;
        GridView1.DataBind();
    }
}

protected void GridView1_PageIndexChanging(object sender, GridViewPageEventArgs e)
{
    GridView1.PageIndex = e.NewPageIndex;
}

protected void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string client = TextBox1.Text;

    SourceDataContext db = new SourceDataContext();

    GridView1.DataSource = from q in db.Cust
                           where q.Client_Name == client
                           orderby q.ID
                           select q;
    GridView1.DataBind();

    //reset page index to 0
    GridView1.PageIndex = 0;
}
}
```

Filtering partially works, however the paging does not. Further, the paging requires the page to be clicked twice for it to be selected.

Thanks.

Comment: i think after assinging new index to your grid view you have to recall the GridView.Bind method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try it.
Save this code in a function let name it BindGrid

```
private void BindGrid()
{
 SourceDataContext db = new SourceDataContext();

    GridView1.DataSource = from q in db.Cust
                           orderby q.ID
                           select q;
    GridView1.DataBind();
}
// Create this method in your code behind
```

and call it in the GridView1_PageIndexChanging after assinging new index

```
protected void GridView1_PageIndexChanging(object sender, GridViewPageEventArgs e)
{
    GridView1.PageIndex = e.NewPageIndex;
    BindGrid();
}
```

Comment: I get the following error: The name 'BindGrid' does not exist in the current context.

Comment: @stats101 First create a method with the name BindGrid or any name with the code I mentioned in my answer. Add this Code to your code behind. You have not created a method due to which you get the error.

Comment: the pagination for the filter called by button1_Click still doesn't work.

Comment: @stats101 set index first  GridView1.PageIndex = 0; then call the GridView1.DataBind() method. in your button event.

Comment: @stats101 why you are setting pageindex to 0 ? there is no need of it.